# Set Login Role using php jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

Anyone Help me To set Login Role for Admin and user the user its already working but I don't know how to put admin login code on a login user

```
function login2(){
    extract($_POST);
    $qry = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user_info where email = '".$email."' and password = '".md5($password)."' ");
    if($qry->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($qry->fetch_array() as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'passwors' && !is_numeric($key))
                $_SESSION['login_'.$key] = $value;
            $this->db->query("UPDATE user_info set attempts = '0' where email = '".$email."' and password = '".md5($password)."' ");

        }
        $ip = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] : isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $this->db->query("UPDATE cart set user_id = '".$_SESSION['login_user_id']."' where client_ip ='$ip' ");
            return 1;
    }else{
        $_SESSION['attempts'] += 1;
        $this->db->query("UPDATE user_info set attempts = '".$_SESSION['attempts']."' where email = '".$email."' ");
        $this->db->query("UPDATE user_info set password = 'sfsdfsdfdsfsdf435345435j3k5h35498f7dsf' where attempts >= 3 ");
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you really using MD5 for your password hash?

Comment: Recommend an [alternate implementation](https://code-boxx.com/password-encrypt-decrypt-php/). Also look up SQL injection and PHP. Spelling `'passwors'` helps too. So you can deny service to a user by logging into their account 3 time?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column in your users table named `user_role` or `role` or something like that for role and use it like 1 for Admin, 2 for User, when user attempts login get the `user_role` value from your users table and store it in your login session along with other user details. Once you have the role in your session you can easily manage user privileges as per their role.

Your table will be like

| id | username | password | user_role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Admin | sfsdfsdfdsfsdf435345435j3k5h35498f7dsf | 1 |
| 2 | User 1 | sfsdfsdfdsfsdasfasf35j3k5h35498f7dsf | 2 |
| 3 | User 2 | sfsasdfasfasf43534535j3k5h35498f7dsf | 2 |